# Slide Menu ( Horizontal )

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery

ASP.Net / Javascript / Jquery

We come across a feature in http://www.cnn.com/TECH/ - Which has slide Menu bar in Tech Pulse section.

Menu slides either automatically after 2 -3 seconds or manually.

Is there any third party  tool to help us or what would be the ideal solution for such scenario's.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easy in vanilla jQuery. Create a div with `display:none` and then use `$('#divid').slideDown();`

http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

Comment: Thank you,I am beginner in Jquery ..!let me try this and get back to you ..!